# Scenekit - multiple rotation of SCNNode and direction of axes

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, rotation, scenekit

I have a SCNNode which i keep on rotating with pan gesture by 90deg increments. The first few rotations are working as intended, by with a scenario where the nodes axes rotate in the oposite direction, the rotation is executed in wrong direction. How can i determine the orientation of the axes after each rotation?

Scenario (using a cube for simplicity):

- i rotate the cube 90deg along Y axis. Y points still up, X now points to the camera, Z points right
- i rotate the cube again 90deg along Y.  X now points left, Z to the camera
- PROBLEM - i now try to rotate 90deg along X axis. Because X got rotated 180 degrees, the rotation is now reversed.

How can i understand when to rotate (-1,0,0) and when (1,0,0) ?

I'm quite new to the world of 3D math, i hope i explained my issue correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research i realised i chose completely wrong approach. The  way to achieve what i want was to  rotate the   node using the axes of the rootNode - this way i don't need to worry about local axes of my node.

**EDIT: updated code based on Xartec's suggestions**

```
let rotation = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(angle,  x, y, Float(0))
let newTransform = SCNMatrix4Mult(bricksNode.transform, rotation)
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
animation.fromValue = bricksNode.transform
animation.toValue = scnScene.rootNode.convertTransform(newTransform,from: nil)
animation.duration = 0.5
bricksNode.addAnimation(animation, forKey: nil)
```

Comment: Using another node to essentially represent worldSpace is not the most straightforward way to achieve what you want. Instead of the dummy node you could use the rootNode if the scene. And instead of worldTransform you could use .transform and multiply the matrices in the reverse order.

Comment: Thanks for valuable input Xartec, i will update the answer!

Comment: One more question if i may - would the same apply if position of the rotating node wasn't (0,0,0) ?

Comment: No, for nodes that have a parent in a different location and possibly rotation things get more complicated. See my the solution on your question here for a more complete approach. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46723827/scenekit-converttransform-of-a-rotated-sub-subnode-based-on-world-axes?noredirect=1#comment80428936_46723827